# Parsing reStructuredText into HTML

Tags: python, restructuredtext, python-sphinx, docutils

I'm making a framework in which I let developers describe their package using reStructuredText. I want to parse that reStructuredText into HTML so I can show it in a GUI.

I'm familiar with the excellent Sphinx, but I've never otherwise parsed reStructuredText. I imagined something like a function that takes a string of reStructuredText, and possibly several additional arguments, and returns a string of HTML.

So I looked into Docutils, which is responsible for parsing reStructuredText. I couldn't understand at all how to find this function. Documentation on the web is spotty. Many of the functions in the `docutils.parsers.rst` module seemed to be geared toward filenames. I don't have filenames! I'm just handling strings.

I tried creating a `Parser` and a `Document` and using the `parse` method, but I just get an error about a missing `.tab_width` setting.

Does anyone know how to parse reStructuredText into HTML?

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
>>> from docutils.core import publish_string
>>> publish_string("*anurag*", writer_name='html')
```

`publish_string` accepts a strings and outputs a string or you can use [publish_parts](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/api/publisher.html#publish-parts-details) to get specific parts of html document e.g.

```
>>> from docutils.core import publish_parts
>>> print publish_parts("*anurag*", writer_name='html')['html_body']
<p><em>anurag</em></p>
```

Comment: Your second suggestion was the more effective one: The `'body'` was exactly what I wanted.

Comment: You should link to the documentation (http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/api/publisher.html#publish-parts-details)! And, FWIW, here are some related code snippets: http://code.activestate.com/recipes/193890-using-rest-restructuredtext-to-create-html-snippet/

Comment: Note, that the `publish_string()` function did not change its name with the switch to Python3 but by default still returns what was a "string" in Python2 but is `bytes` now! OTOH, the values of the "parts" dictionary returned by `publish_parts()` are of type `str` ("unicode" in Python 2).