# Process string using sphinx

Tags: python, import, python-sphinx

I was wondering whether it is possible to process a string in python, using sphinx. Basically, I would like to pass a string containing restructured text to sphinx, and then generate the corresponding HTML output. I meant something like this

```
import sphinx.something
s = 'some restructured text'
html_out = sphinx.something(s)
```

However, I could not find anything along these lines. So, is this possible, and if so, how would one do this?

Comment: Maybe look at [docutils](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/), which Sphinx is based on.

Comment: Thanks, but I think I really need the sphinx services.

Comment: What are you trying to do? It doesn't really make sense to process one string in Sphinx, because Sphinx is all about linking between documents etc.

Comment: But even then, I should be able to process an rst string, shouldn't I? I am trying to write a simple editor for rst, so I would take the string from the text window, compile it, and then display the output in an HTML viewer.

Comment: Have a look here: http://pymolurus.blogspot.com/2012/01/documentation-viewer-for-sphinx.html

Comment: Oh, that really looks like it! Thanks for the pointer!

Comment: How about http://stackoverflow.com/a/6654576/407651?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I have used pygments before, but the problem with that and docutils is that you can't include snippets from external files. sphinx is really significantly better in that regard.

Comment: @v923z: Why do you bring up Pygments? It is not mentioned in the answer that I linked to. And in the question you don't say anything about including snippets from external files.

Comment: Because I believe that if you want to have syntax highlighting, you will need pygments. I might be wrong, though... Sphinx automatically includes that. And I didn't say anything about including snippets, because I clearly stated that I wanted to process a sphinx string. That should include snippets, and many other things.

Answer (score 2):

The quickest solution I've seen is:

```
from docutils.examples import html_body

def rst(rstStr):
return html_body(rstStr, input_encoding='utf-8', 
                 output_encoding='utf-8').strip()
```

I'd be interested myself in better solutions..