# How to create a new document in Sphinx/docutils by API?

Tags: vhdl, documentation, python-sphinx, autodoc, docutils

I' writing a new extension for Sphinx as a domain offering multiple directives, roles and indices for the hardware description language VHDL. This extension shall be able to auto document language constructs. In VHDL, we have e.g. entities/architectures or packages/package bodies. These could be documented as pairs in individual docutils documents, so each language construct has an individual URL (or page in PDF) in the documentation.

I'm looking for a solution to create new documents in Sphinx/docutils. According to the docutils API description, a document is the root element to a doctree (documentation tree). According to the Sphinx documentation, directives are items in the doctree that get consumed and can emit new nodes to the surrounding doctree. So it's a translation/replacement approach.

Non of the documentation seams to offer a way to create new document.

Looking at the `autodoc` extensions, there are 2 sides. There is `sphinx.ext.autodoc` coming with Sphinx. It offers `.. auto***` directives to automatically document Python language constructs. It requires a user to place dozens to hundreds of auto-directives into the ReStructured Text. Of cause it automatically document e.g. classes or modules, but for a huge project it's a lot of work.

In addition, there is [autoapi](https://github.com/carlos-jenkins/autoapi), which reads the Python code for a given package or module and generates ReST files on the fly when Sphinx is loaded. Then these files - containing auto-directives - are processed.

As I understand, autoapi workaround the problem of creating now docutils documents, by writing ReST files, so Sphinx generates document instances with a doctree, and then autodoc from Sphinx jumps in and replaces them with content from doc-strings.

**So my questions after all investigations I did so far:**

- How can I create docutils or Sphinx document to get a HTML file per item I want to auto document?
- Or do I always need to do a hack like autoapi from Carlos Jenkins and create ReST files as dummies or with auto directives, so I can use the replacement capabilities of Sphinx/autodoc from directive to documentation nodes?

---

Why don't I like the autoapi approach? I have parse VHDL files as input in form of a Code Document Object Model (CodeDOM). I don't want to serialize parse VHDL file into ReST, to parse it again, construct again a model of my source files, so I can then translate to documentation nodes like sections, paragraphs and lists.

I have all available to generate doc-nodes for docutils, but I need multiple documents, so I can distribute the content to hundreds of documentations file (HTML files).

Comment: Interesting, I have started to do something very similar in the EDA domain as well (SKILL code for now). I am too struggling with the amount of documentation aimed at our use-case, so I resorted to asking a LLM and made some progress this way. I'll write a short answer with what I understood as of now. Did you make some progress on your end?

Comment: I believe I found a solution to my remaining issue with this approach. I will edit my answer to your question later, but meanwhile you can have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/77759771/3795597 for a better example.

Comment: You can get a "document tree" object from a (possibly empty) string using `docutils.core.publish_doctree()`. (See the source `docutils/core.py` for details.)

Answer (score 2):

I am in a similar situation, and I am right now looking at generating an html file per source file. The following is a snapshot of where I was at when I found your question:

You can tell sphinx to parse other file types at build time. In conf.py:

```py
source_suffix = {
    '.rst': 'restructuredtext',
    '.something': 'my_language',  # Will call the my_language parser for .something files
}
```

Then create your own extension (could be part of the VHDL domain you created). Either in `my_extension.py` or `my_extension/{__init__.py,etc}`

```
from docutils import nodes
from sphinx.parsers import Parser

class MyLanguageParser(Parser):
    supported = ("my_language",)  # Declate supported languages
    def parse(self, inputstring, document):
        # Do something more complex, but a document can be created from the file (contents in inputstrings)
        txt = nodes.Text('HI')
        document += txt

def setup(app):  # This is called when loading the extension
    app.add_source_suffix('.something', 'my_language')
    app.add_source_parser(MyLanguageParser)

    return {'version': '0.1'}  # Optional, but nice to version your extension
```

Now, when calling `sphinx-build`, such as with `make html`, your parser will be called and generate an output page per input file.

---

To answer the title of your question, you can also programatically construct new arbitrary documents this way:

```py
from sphinx.util.docutils import new_document
from docutils.core import publish_doctree, publish_from_doctree
from docutils import nodes

# create a new document
doc = new_document('mydoc')
txt = nodes.Text('HI')
doc += txt

# Alternatively, you can also build it from rst:
rst = """
Doc Title
=========

some content
"""
doc = publish_doctree(rst)

with open('mydoc.html', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(publish_from_doctree(doc, writer_name='html'))
```

The last part is taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32168938/3795597).

Comment: I hope this helps someone else. For now, I am stuggling to generate documents by appending nodes like that.

Comment: I am currently blocked at this point, I will probably edit this answer as well if I find a solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77679964/set-document-title-with-custom-sphinx-parser

Comment: I wrote a new Sphinx extension to integrate doc-string coverage reports into the documentation's appendix. It would be nice if I could create subpages for every module. See my current state here: https://github.com/HunterMcGushion/docstr_coverage/issues/138

Comment: I think that's not what I need, though its interesting new knowledge about Sphinx for me. The parser/reader approach from Sphinx is meant for different documentation formats like ReST, MD or ASCIIdoc. I my case I read sources files for language parsing. Imagine I would do so with Python sources and handover the Python directory. It doesn't feel right. The question is more like how to add `doc` from your example into the big toctree of Sphinx. There seems to be no `app.toctree.add_document(position/path, doc)`.

Comment: I raised a question at Sphinx issues: https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/issues/11934